# Increase in Value button

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I wish to be able to create a button that increase the number of *upvotes* and decreases the number of *downvotes*

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM champion_counters_b WHERE champion_name='" . $search_result . "'");

echo "<table class='champion_counters' border='1'><tr><th>Champion Counter</th><th>Up Votes</th><th>Down Votes</th></tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['champion_counter'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['upvotes'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['downvotes'] . "</td>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

As you can see, I am currently echoing a table until there are no search results left for the input. As you can see `$row['upvotes'], $row['downvotes']` these are the things that i'd like to be able to generate a button for, on each row.

```
"Upvote" => upvotes + 1 => 1, 2, 3, etc
"Downvote" => downvotes - 1 => -1, -2, -3, etc
```

**tl;dr: Would like to be able to generate buttons for each row to increase the number of upvotes and decrease the number of downvotes**

Comment: Firstly make sure your HTML and PHP is proper, you're missing the clossing </tr> tag and you have a ; to many. Secondly, what have you tried thus far yourself?

Answer (score 1):

This might not be what you are looking for, but as far as I understood, this would be my solution:

You will most probably have some kind of primary key in your database. You do actually get it here as you perform a "SELECT *", e.g. retrieve all columns.

Based on the primary key, you can now implement your down- and upvoting functionality. You could for example insert the following into your while-loop (let $row['key'] be the primary key):

```
echo "<td><a href='action.php?do=up&id=" . $row['key'] . "'>Upvote</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href='action.php?do=down&id=" . $row['key'] . "'>Downvote</a></td>";
```

Using this, each table row will have two links which will send the user to an action.php and append some GET-Parameters to the URL. The GET-Parameters are "do", which will tell you what to do (either up or down) and "id", which is the primary key.

In action.php, you can read those GET-Parameters and perform any further action, like updating the database. You can get them like this:

```
$action = $_GET['do'];
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Depending on $action, you can now update the downvotes or the upvotes. You can identify the item to update with $id.

Comment: Thats a good idea! Thanks for that, I'll get round to trying it sometime and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Just an issue, this doesn't seem to work? - It seems to pull the value of the actual output rather than the position of the value in the table. (there is more than one row that will be printed with a common value/id)