# Increase in Value button "mrk2"

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

*Update post for: [Increase in Value button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21230796/increase-in-value-button)*

I made a post asking about how make an increase value button. I got one decent answer, I tried it and it didn't work.

**Original:**

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM champion_counters_b WHERE champion_name='" . $search_result . "'");

echo "<table class='champion_counters' border='1'><tr><th>Champion Counter</th><th>Up Votes</th><th>Down Votes</th></tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['champion_counter'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['upvotes'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['downvotes'] . "</td>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

**Current:**

```
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM champion_counters_b WHERE champion_name='" . $search_result . "'");

    echo "<table class='champion_counters' border='1'><tr><th>Champion Counter</th><th>Up Votes</th><th>Down Votes</th></tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['champion_counter'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td><a href='action.php?do=up&id=" . $row['upvotes'] . "'>Upvote [" . $row['upvotes'] . "]</a></td>";
        echo "<td><a href='action.php?do=down&id=" . $row['downvotes'] . "'>Downvote [" . $row['downvotes'] . "]</a></td>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

**action.php:**

```
    $action = $_GET['do'];
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    if ($action=="up") {
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE champion_counters_b SET" . $id . "=" . $id+1 . "'");
    }
    elseif ($action=="down") {
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE champion_counters_b SET" . $id . "=" . $id-1 . "'");
    }
    else {echo "error: 002 / voting error";}

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

As you can see I implemented the changes that were recommended and that could of worked, but they didn't rather than updating the data it did nothing. As when pressing `"upvote"/"downvote"` it grabbed the current value as `$id` rather than the position of the data to update it.

**tl;dr: I tried a fix from the previous thread, it didn't do anything. Help please?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry if I have been unclear, let me give it another try:

You insert a link into your table, which calls an action.php. The action.php updates the database. The information needed for updating are passed as GET-parameters.

For updating the database, you will need to know WHAT to do, and secondly, WHICH database entry is actually affected.

Step by step:

First, you have to insert the links into your table:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM champion_counters_b WHERE champion_name='" . $search_result . "'");

echo "<table class='champion_counters' border='1'><tr><th>Champion Counter</th><th>Up Votes</th><th></th><th>Down Votes</th><th></th></tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['champion_counter'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['upvotes'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='action.php?do=up&id=" . $row['key'] . "'>Upvote</a></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['downvotes'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='action.php?do=down&id=" . $row['key'] . "'>Downvote</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

On clicking the link, we are sending two pieces of information to the action.php.

1. The action we have to perform, either up- or downvoting. It tells us WHAT to do.
2. The id of the element we have to up- or downvote. The id tells us WHICH element is affected, and not the number of votes an element has.

As mentioned in my answer to your previous post, `$row['key']` should contain the primary key of your database, e.g. an unique identifier. You should have such an identifier in your database, otherwise you cannot make a reference to a specific database entry. However, as we want to update the vote count for a very specific database entry, we need a possibility to uniquely identify this database entry.

In your action.php, you have to do the following:

```
$action = $_GET['do'];
$id = $_GET['id'];

if ($action=="up") {
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE champion_counters_b SET upvotes = upvotes + 1 WHERE key = " . $id . "'");
}
elseif ($action=="down") {
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE champion_counters_b SET downvotes = downvotes - 1 WHERE key = " . $id . "'");    }
else {echo "error: 002 / voting error";}

mysqli_close($con);
```

We use the id value to select the database entry we have to update. This is done by `WHERE key = $id` in the UPDATE-statement. The current vote count is taken from the database itself - there is no need to pass the current vote count in the GET-parameters.

After you have updated your database, you can redirect to the original page and reload your table. Then, the updated vote count should show up.

Comment: Had to edit the code abit, but thats to be expected, it works thanks!